# How to invoke file from resource folder java

Tags: java, spring, file, spring-boot

This is my code to get file from resource folder,

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File fXmlFile = new File(classLoader.getResource("XMLDocument/Config.xml").getFile());
```

It's working fine in local, after generating docker image and deployed in aws fargate container it's throws exception,

```
"error_message": "/usr/local/bin/file:/usr/local/bin/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/XMLDocument/Config.xml (No such file or directory)"
```

Comment: Check that you build tool add the file into jar.

Comment: First build target resource (jar, war). Open it and be sure that files from resources folder there.

Answer (score 2):

Add a slash in front of the path:

```
File fXmlFile = new File(classLoader.getResource("/XMLDocument/DoctypesConfig.xml").getFile());
```

Comment: @annamalaikumaran can you take a look into your jar file if the file exists?

Comment: @annamalaikumaran you realy Need the file or can you work with the Input stream?

Comment: if i put slash in front of the path, in local itself it's not working

Comment: @annamalaikumaran What means *local*

Comment: @annamalaikumaran Looks like we Need more informations about your Project structure. Where is the class containing the code located?

Comment: From that highlighted service i am accessing, the file DoctypesConfig.xml in resource folder

Comment: please find the screenshot

Comment: can you try getClass().getResource("/XMLDocument/DoctypesConfig.XML")